# Is it possible to compute higher order queens contiguity in PySAL?

Tags: pysal

I'm computing a spatial weights matrix in PySAL using Queens Contiguity. My problem is that I would like to consider areas that are contiguous to the first set of neighbours (ie. 2nd or even 3rd order contiguity.)

Reading the docs here...

https://pysal.org/libpysal/generated/libpysal.weights.Queen.html#libpysal.weights.Queen

...leads me to conclude that higher order contiguity is not possible with the Queens weighting in PySAL since I can't find a parameter for it.

GeoDa seems to have the option as illustrated here:

[image: GeoDa Queens dialog]

Source: https://geodacenter.github.io/workbook/4a_contig_weights/lab4a.html#queen-contiguity

Am I missing something or is it not possible in PySAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using [higher order weights](https://pysal.org/libpysal/generated/libpysal.weights.higher_order.html#libpysal.weights.higher_order).

Comment: Great, that makes sense and is very flexible. To elaborate for those finding this answer later the function is called weights.higher_order and can be applied to any weights object. So in my case I compute Queens Contiguity and output the weight object w and then supply that to the higher_order function with my desired k-value for the order.

Comment: @hexamon thanks for the comment, that was evry helpful

Comment: weights.higher_order is really helpful, but is there any way to include the lower orders?